# Python pseudo-immutable object field

Tags: python, hash, immutability

I currently need to partially create a Python object and be able to update it for some time. Although, I must not be able to update it once I used the object as a dictionary key.

Of course there is the solution of marking the fields as private, which is mostly a warning for the programmer, and I will actually go for that solution.

But I stumbled on another solution and I want to know if this could be a good idea, or if it could simply go horribly wrong. Here it is:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self._bar = bar
        self._has_been_hashed = False

    def __hash__(self):
        self._has_been_hashed = True
        return self._bar.__hash__()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._bar == other._bar

    def __copy__(self):
        return Foo(self._bar)

    def set_bar(self, bar):
        if self.has_been_hashed:
            raise FooIsNowImmutable
        else:
            self._bar = bar
```

Some testing proved it to work as desired, I can no longer use set_bar once I, say, used my object as a dictionary key.

What do you think? Is it a good idea? Will it turn against me? Is there an easier way? And is it somehow a bad practice?

Comment: It will also become immutable if someone just calls `hash(obj)` on your object, or uses it in a set.  Are you okay with that?

Comment: I guess it would be okay, since when you retrieve the hash of an object you assume it will never change. So you do assume it would later be locked.

Comment: Side-note: Using an `@property` would make this more natural; name it `bar`, have the getter be trivial (`return self._bar`) and the setter would check your "is locked" flag before performing a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it that way is a bit fragile, since you never know when something might be used as a dictionary key, or when its `hash` might be called for some other reason.  An object isn't supposed to "know" whether it's being used as a dictionary key.  It will be confusing to have code that may raise an exception just because some other code somewhere else put the object in a dictionary.

Following the Python philosophy of "explicit is better than implicit", it would be safer to just give your object a method called `.finalize()` or `.lock()` or something, which would set a flag indicating the object is immutable.  You could also reverse the exception-raising logic, so that `__hash__` raises an exception if the object is not yet locked (rather than mutation raising an exception if the object has been hashed).

You would then call `.lock()` when you're ready to make the object immutable.  It makes more sense to explicitly set it immutable when you're done with whatever mutating you need to do, rather than implicitly assuming that as soon as you use it in a dictionary, you're done mutating it.

Comment: Thank you, a lock() function does sound like a way better alternative! Also, I just realized that something that might be a problem is if the object is no longer used as a key... in this case there is no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but I'm not sure I'd recommend it. Why do you need it in a dictionary?

It requires a lot more awareness of the state of the object... think a file object. Would you put one in a dictionary? It has to be opened for a lot of the functions to work, and once it's closed, you can't do them anymore. The user has to be aware in the surrounding code which state the object is in.

For files, that makes sense - after all, you don't normally hold files open across large parts of your program, or if you do, they have very defined init and close codes; something similar has to make sense for your object. Especially if you have some APIs that take the object, but expect an immutable version, and others that take the same object, but expect to change it...

I have used the lock method before, and it works well for complex, read-only objects that you want to initialize once and then make sure no one is messing with. E.G. you load a copy of a (say, English) dictionary from disk... it has to be mutable while you are populating it, but you don't want anyone to accidentally modify it, so locking it is a great idea. I would only use it if it was a one-time lock though - something you are locking and unlocking seems like a recipe for disaster.

There are two solutions IMHO if you just want to create a version you can use in hashable places. First is to explicitly create an immutable copy when you put it in a dictionary - `tuple` and `frozenset` are examples of this sort of behaviour... if you want to put a `list` in a `dict`, you can't, but you can create a `tuple` from it first, and that can be hashed. Create a `frozen` version of your object, then it's very clear by looking at the object type whether it's expected to be mutable or immutable, and so cases where it was used incorrectly are easily seen.

Second, if you *really* want it to be hashable, but need it to be mutable... that's actually legal, but implemented a little different. It goes back to the idea of hashing... hashing is used both for optimized lookups, and equality.

The first is to ensure you can get objects back... you put something in a dictionary, and it hashes to a value of 4 - goes in slot 4. Then you modify it. Then you go to look it up again, and now it hashes to 9 - there's nothing in slot 9, or worse, a different object, and you're broken.

Second is equality - for things like sets, I need to know if my object is already in there. I can hash, but if you know anything about hashing, you still need to check equality to check for hash collisions.

That doesn't preclude supporting `__hash__` *and* being mutable, but it's unusual. You need to decide for your item what makes it the same, even though it's mutable. What you need to do then is give each object a unique id. Technically, you may be able to get away with `id(self)`, but something like the `uuid` module is probably a better possibility. The UUID4 (or technically, the hash of the UUID4) is what determines both the hash and equality; two objects that contain the same UUID4 should be the exact same object; two objects that have the exact same data but a different UUID4 would be different object.